# Почему при присваивании результата функции не вызывается оператор присваивания

Tags: c++, c++14

Имеется код в мэйн :

```
my_complex::complex cd = my_complex::complex::add_complex(ca, cb);
```

Функция `add_complex(ca, cb)` имеет следующий прототип:

```
static complex add_complex(const complex&, const complex&);
```

Оба оператора присваивания для класса `complex` объявлены в классе и при присваивании вида

```
ca = cb; //срабатывает копирующее присваивание
ca = complex(5,8); //срабатывает перемещающее присваивание
```

операторы работают. Однако в коде, представленном в верху вопроса (присваивание результата функции), не вызывается ни один из операторов и конструкторов. Является ли такое поведение результатом оптимизации компилятора, который пишет результат функции прямо в пременную-получатель, или это поведение объясняется чем-то иным?

Компилятор g++. C++14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оператор присваивания применяется к объектам, которые уже созданы. Однако в этом предложении

```
my_complex::complex cd = my_complex::complex::add_complex(ca, cb);
```

только создается объект. Поэтому здесь будет вызван конструктор. В общем случае здесь вызывается конструктор копирования или конструктор перемещения в зависимости от того, какой из них объявлен.

Компилятору разрешается опустить вызов конструктора копирования или конструктора перемещения и создать рбъект "на месте" в `cd`. Однако тем не менее конструктор копирования или конструктор перемещения должны быть доступны.

Поэтому также не следует включать в конструктор копирования или конструктор перемещения какие-то побочные эффекты, которые не имеют место в обчных конструкторах при создании объектов.

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public: 
    A( int x )
    {
        std::cout << "A::A( int ) with x = " << x  << std::endl;
    }

    A( A &&a )
    {
        std::cout << "A::A( A && )" << std::endl;
    }

    A & operator =( A && )
    {
        std::cout << "A::operator =" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    // объект создается; вызывается конструктор
    A a = A( 10 );

    // объект уже создан; вызывается оператор присваивания
    a = A( 20 );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
A::A( int ) with x = 10
A::A( int ) with x = 20
A::operator =
```

В этой программе компилятор пропускает вызов конструктора перемещения. Тем не менее, как уже я сказал выше, он должен быть доступен. Если, например, его сделать закрытым, то код не будет компилироваться

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
private:
    A( A &&a )
    {
        std::cout << "A::A( A && )" << std::endl;
    }


public: 
    A( int x )
    {
        std::cout << "A::A( int ) with x = " << x  << std::endl;
    }

    A & operator =( A && )
    {
        std::cout << "A::operator =" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    // объект создается; вызывается конструктор
    A a = A( 10 );

    // объект уже создан; вызывается оператор присваивания
    a = A( 20 );

    return 0;
}

prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:6:5: error: 'A::A(A&&)' is private
     A( A &&a )
     ^
prog.cpp:27:17: error: within this context
     A a = A( 10 );
                 ^
```

Имейте в виду, что MS VC++ (по крайней мере некоторые его версии) имеет баг и позволяет компилировать данный код.:)

Из стандарта C++ (12.8 Copying and moving class objects)

> 31 When certain criteria are met, **an implementation is allowed to
>   omit the copy/move construction of a class object**, even if the
>   copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side
>   effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the source and
>   target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two different ways
>   of referring to the same object, and the destruction of that object
>   occurs at the later of the times when the two objects would have been
>   destroyed without the optimization.123 This elision of copy/move
>   operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following
>   circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):

Answer (score 2):

В коде

```
my_complex::complex cd = my_complex::complex::add_complex(ca, cb);
```

нет никакого оператора присваивания. Это не "присваивание результата функции", как вы его неправильно назвали. Здесь делается именно и только *инициализация*. Причем из-за того, что тип левой части совпадает с типом правой, такая *инициализация копированием* расценивается как *прямая инициализация*

```
my_complex::complex cd(my_complex::complex::add_complex(ca, cb));
```

А далее компилятор просто устранил промежуточные временные объекты и конструирует результат функции прямо в `cd` - работает *copy elision* и *return value optimization*. Т.е. конструктор-то вызывается, но именно тот, который вызывается внутри `add_complex` (содержимое которой вы, однако, не показываете) и вызывается он сразу для `cd`. Таким образом копирования/перемещения делать не нужно.

Такого рода "сокращение" процесса инициализации и устранение "ненужных" промежуточных временных объектов и копирований/перемещений открыто разрешено спецификацией языка, даже если конструкторы копирования/перемещения имеют побочные эффекты.